# Why doesn't my String comparison code work?

Tags: java, string, compare

this code throws

> Error "Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>
> at basic2.compareStrPractice.main(compareStrPractice.java:15)"

```
int i;
    char[] chr1 = {};
    char[] chr2 = {};
    String s1 = "man";
    String s2 = "nam";

        for ( i= 0; i<s1.length(); i++){

            chr1[i] = (char)s1.charAt(i);
            chr2[i] = (char)s2.charAt(i);

        }
        if ((chr1[0] == chr2[2]) && (chr1[1] == chr2[1]) && (chr1[2] == chr2[0])){

            System.out.println("They are Palindrom!");
        }

}
```

i want to print the statement. but it throws ArrayOutOfBoundary Error.

Comment: I disagree about the close vote; IMHO this question should be left open. It has desired behaviour (“i want to print the statement”), specific problem (with stacktrace and all) and lovely short code to demonstrate. Well done for a new Stack Overflow user.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the way you declared the character arrays.

```
char[] chr1 = {};
```

The way you did it the array is defined with a size of 0.

In Java you need to specify the size of the array like this:

```
char[] chr1 = new char[3];
```

What this does is it declares a char array with a predefined size of 3.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to write a code for palindrome it is wrong in many ways but for the error, You are initializing an empty array of char of 0 size, use this

```
char[] chr1 = new char[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also first check the lengths to ensure they are the same.  Otherwise, you may get another `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. This will happen when you use the longer string's length to index the shorter character array.

Since for longer strings you don't want to have many comparisons in a single `if` statement you should use a loop and compare starting at the beginning of one array and at the end of the other.  So if the length is 5  you would compare characters at 0 and 4, then 1 and 3, then 2, and 2, then 3, and 1 and so forth.

Here are some other tips that might help.  You don't need to create empty arrays and fill them.  String provides that capability.

`char[] chr1 = s1.toCharArray();`

In fact, you don't need to assign to a String variable.

`char[] chr1 = "man".toCharArray();`

And just in case you ever want to assign to an array of String instead of char you can do this to hold an array of single character strings.

`String[] str1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");`